# Match data between dataframes columns and then paste the data avaliable on one of them

Tags: r, data-science

I know that the title could be a Little confussing, but basically this is what I want.

Lets supposse I have a a dataframe of this form

```
P_SEXO P_EDADR COD_ENCUESTAS
   <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>
1      2      16            74
2      2       9            75
3      2      18            75
4      2      11            75
5      2      11            76
6      2       1            76
```

As you can see, theres some values that repeats on `COD_ENCUESTAS`, this is because its like an índex in another dataframe (df2).

Df2 have a form like this:

```
COD_ENCUESTAS VA1_ESTRATO
          <dbl>       <dbl>
1           74          24
2           75          23
3           76          12
4           77           23
5           78           14
6           79          11
```

I want output:

```
P_SEXO P_EDADR COD_ENCUESTAS    VA1_ESTRTO 
   <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1      2      16            74    24
2      2       9            75    23
3      2      18            75    23
4      2      11            75    23
5      2      11            76    12
6      2       1            76    12
```

Thnaks beforehand
-lasagna

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: simply do a left join between these two dataframe by `COD_ENCUESTAS` like `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2,  by = "COD_ENCUESTAS") `

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join of dplyr and tidyverse.
Here is an example of the code you could use:

```
df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by="COD_ENCUESTAS")
```

df should be the dataframe you're looking for.

Best,